# count specific string in column on a dataframe python

Tags: python, string, pandas, dataframe, count

I have a (101×1766) dataframe and I put a sample down.

```
Index  Id  Brand1   Brand2   Brand3
0      1   NaN      Good     Bad
1      2   Bad      NaN      NaN
2      3   NaN      NaN      VeryBad
3      4   Good     NaN      NaN
4      5   NaN      Good     VeryGood
5      6   VeryBad  Good     NaN
```

What I want to achieve is a table like that

```
Index  VeryBad   Bad    Good   VeryGood
Brand1  1        1      0      0
Brand2  0        0      3      0
Brand3  1        1      0      1
```

I could not find a solution even a wrong one at all.

So, hope to see your help

Comment: Also: [pandas count values in each column of a dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22888434/7851470)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let us do two steps : `melt` + `crosstab`

```
s=df.melt(['Id','Index'])
yourdf=pd.crosstab(s.variable,s.value)
yourdf
value     Bad  Good  VeryBad  VeryGood
variable                              
Brand1      1     1        1         0
Brand2      0     3        0         0
Brand3      1     0        1         1
```

Answer (score 3):

Select all columns without first by [`DataFrame.iloc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.iloc.html), then count values by `value_counts`, replace non matched missing values, convert to integers, transpose and last for change order of columns use `reindex`:

```
cols = ['VeryBad','Bad','Good','VeryGood']
df = df.iloc[:, 1:].apply(pd.value_counts).fillna(0).astype(int).T.reindex(cols, axis=1)
print (df)
        VeryBad  Bad  Good  VeryGood
Brand1        1    1     1         0
Brand2        0    0     3         0
Brand3        1    1     0         1
```

Answer (score 3):

Here is an approach using [`melt`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.melt.html) and [`pivot_table`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pivot_table.html):

```
(df.melt(id_vars='Id')
 .pivot_table(index='variable',
              columns='value',
              aggfunc='count',
              fill_value=0))
```

[out]

```
          Id                      
value    Bad Good VeryBad VeryGood
variable                          
Brand1     1    1       1        0
Brand2     0    3       0        0
Brand3     1    0       1        1
```

Answer (score 1):

Another way is : [`get_dummies`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.get_dummies.html) with [`transpose`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.T.html) + [`groupby()+sum()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html)

```
m=pd.get_dummies(df.set_index('Id').T)
final=m.groupby(m.columns.str.split('_').str[1],axis=1).sum()
```

---

```
        Bad  Good  VeryBad  VeryGood
Brand1    1     1        1         0
Brand2    0     3        0         0
Brand3    1     0        1         1
```