# How to pivot table and aggregate on multiple columns?

Tags: pandas, pivot-table

I have a dataframe which looks like this:

```
pd.DataFrame({"id": [1,2,2,1], "col1": ['a', 'b', 'c', 'b'], "col2": ['z', 'c', 'a', 'd'], "col3": ['d','a','d','z']})

    id  col1    col2    col3
0   1   a       z       d
1   2   b       c       a
2   2   c       a       d
3   1   b       d       z
```

I would like to transform it into this:

```
    id  a   b   c   d   z
0   1   1   1   0   2   2
1   2   2   1   2   1   0
```

In other words, I would like, for each id, the number of occurences of each value in col1, col2 and col3.

I found this almost similar problem ([Pivot Tables or Group By for Pandas?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30679467/pivot-tables-or-group-by-for-pandas)) but as I understand it doesn't work for multiple columns.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22888434/pandas-count-values-in-each-column-of-a-dataframe

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`DataFrame.melt`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.melt.html) with [`crosstab`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.crosstab.html), last data cleaning [`DataFrame.rename_axis`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.rename_axis.html) and [`DataFrame.reset_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html):

```
df1 = df.melt('id')
df = pd.crosstab(df1['id'], df1['value']).rename_axis(None, axis=1).reset_index()
print (df)
   id  a  b  c  d  z
0   1  1  1  0  2  2
1   2  2  1  2  1  0
```